# How do you calculate the sum of a specific row in a list of matrices

Tags: r, lapply, purrr

I have data in matrices and the matrices are stored in a list, and I want the sum of the a specific row in each matrix.

some example data

```
A1<-matrix(0:9, nrow=5, ncol=2)
A2<-matrix(10:19, nrow=5, ncol = 2)
A3<-matrix(20:29, nrow=5, ncol = 2)
Mylist<-list(A1, A2, A3)
```

I can get the sum of all rows in each matrix with

```
lapply(Mylist, function(x) apply(x, 1, sum) )
```

but I only want the sum of a specific row, could be row 1, could be row 4, depending on what I want to look at.  I know I can read it off of the results I generate with the code above but I want a cleaner solution that only gives me the results.  Thanks

Comment: Do you want the sum of the same row index in each matrix?

Comment: yes, but a solution to different indices would be nice to know also.  Thanks

Comment: Updated to show how to do different indices with `map2()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`purrr:map()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).

If you know the output type (in this case, seems to be all integers), you can be more specific, like `map_int()`.  With `map()` you'll get a list back, with a specific `map` version, like `map_int()`, you get a vector back instead.

```
library(tidyverse)

ix <- 3 # let's say we want the sum of the third row

map_int(Mylist, ~sum(.x[ix, ]))
[1] 9 29 49
```

If the row index you care about changes per matrix, you can use [`map2()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) instead, which takes two inputs of the same length:

```
ixs <- c(1, 2, 3)

map2_int(Mylist, ixs, ~sum(.x[.y, ]))
[1]  5 27 49
```

Alternately, if you need to work in base R, you can just take the desired index (here, `ix`) of `sum()`, you don't need `apply()` inside `lapply()`:

```
lapply(Mylist, function(x) sum(x[ix, ]))

[[1]]
[1] 9

[[2]]
[1] 29

[[3]]
[1] 49
```

Comment: You don't need the `apply` in the base R solution `lapply(Mylist, function(x) sum(x[3,]))` will do it. `map_int` is comparable to `Map`, which is the same as `lapply` if you only have one input argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
one.row.sum <- function(df, row.num) lapply(Mylist, function(df) sum(df[row.num, ]))

one.row.sum(Mylist, 1)
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 25

[[3]]
[1] 45
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.